# Find an exact match in MongoDB of nested objects in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[Image with the database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im0Dc.png)

Hi guys i have trouble to select the name="Clothing"
i have tried .find and element Match but i cannot make it work...
Can anyone help?

Comment: `{"categories.name": "Clothing"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be `db.yourCollection.find( {"categories.name": "Clothing"} )`

Read the mongodb documentation, it's great !

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/